# Как добавить код php на страницу WordPress у которой есть родительская страница

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: скрин]Как добавить код php на страницу WordPress у которой есть родительская страница

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код такой (внутри главного цила WordPress, например, в шаблоне страницы)

```
if ( get_the_ID()->post_parent ) {
    // ваш код
}
```

Comment: У меня есть страница "адресные таблички" у неё отображается родительская страница "наружная реклама" шаблон - "базовый шаблон". У "наружной рекламы"  шаблон - "шаблон 2". я вставил код html-php в "шаблон 2", но на странице  "адресные таблички" он не отображается. В чём ошибка?

Comment: а как вы хотите увидеть результат, вставляя код в дрйгой шаблон? У вас какой шаблон для "адресные таблички"? "базовый шаблон"? Вот туда и вставляйте.

Comment: я так понимаю "базовый шаблон"(так он обозначен в редакторе) это index.php, а этот файл вообще пустой. когда я поменял у "адресных табличек" шаблон на "шаблон 2" то мой код отобразился на этой странице, но поверх контента(см. скрин)

Comment: У вас в теме должен быть файл page.php, он и есть базовый шаблон. Почитайте тут про иерархию шаблонов WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Спасибо большое! буду разбираться